# Runtime error 5 while using Mid()

Tags: vba

I am working with string in vba. I would like to do something like this:

```
Dim  matchprodat, matchtxt As MatchCollection
    rega2lhex.Pattern = "[\\][\w]*"
    regprodat.Pattern = "(Datensatz:|Projekt:)[\s\w*,*]*[\\\w]*"
    \\ I am reading each line of a text file 
    Set matchprodat = regprodat.Execute(line)
    If matchprodat.Count <> 0 Then
     Set matcha2lhex = rega2lhex.Execute(matchprodat.Item(0))
     DCMname = DCMfilename + "<>" + Mid(matcha2lhex.Item(0), 2)
    End if
```

but I am getting the error: `Run-time error '5': "Invalid procedure call or argument"`

the  `matcha2lhex.Item(0)` is not empty and has the length of 8. What cause this error in Mid()?

If I am watching the value:
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your answer with a larger sample of code? As we don't know the type or content of `matcha2lhex` then it's going to be very difficult (if not impossible) to diagnose the exact nature of your problem.

Comment: I have edited my post,my original code is very long, I have showed you a summry of the block

Comment: @Kaja in VBA you would rather concatenate string using the `&` instead of `+`. The `+` only applies when working with Strings which I am not sure is the case in your sample.

Comment: @mehowI have changed the code but get the same error

Comment: Can you show your entire regexp code so we can test it?

Comment: Isnt there an issue in the syntax of Mid function? it should contain 3 parameters?

Comment: @Peekay no, the third argument is optional for the `Mid` function.  I can't say otherwise what the problem should be, though. When I try to use `mid` on a matchcollection.item(0) it works as I would expect...